# PivotTable - Calculate value depending on combination of row labels

Tags: excel, pivot-table

**WARNING - Using Excel 2011 for Macs, inexperienced user**

Hi All,

I have a sheet in Excel with a bunch of categorical fields and some numerical ones as well. Let's say it looks like the following:

[image]

I would like to make a pivot table that will display the average click rate (**avg_click_rate**) of the unique combinations of [**year**, **region**], i.e. *the combinations of fields in the pivottable's rows section*.

For example, the **avg_click_rate** of [**years**=5] is:

(0.5*10)**/**(10 +5 ) **+** (0.6*5)**/**(10+5) = 0.53

while the **avg_click_rate** of [**region**=north] is:

(0.6*5)**/**(5+20) **+** (0.2*20)**/**(5+20) = 0.28

and the **avg_click_rate** of [**years**=5, **region**=south] is:

(0.5*10)/10 = 0.5

I know I have to make a custom Calculated Field to do this, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to code the formula. Any help would be seriously, seriously appreciated.

To be clear, my formula would be:

SUM{ (**click_rate** * **number_members**) / SUM{**number_members**} }

where the numerator is a single value for each row included in the unique combination of [**year**, **region**], while the denominator is a constant - the total **number_members** for the unique combination of [**year**, **region**].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new column in your source table:

```
product = click_rate * number_members
```

And then create a Calculated Field in the pivot table:

```
CF = product / number_members
```

Comment: Pcofre, that is an incredibly simple answer (it works - thank you!) and I am still slightly confused as to how it's working. Does the Caculated field take SUM(product)/SUM(number_members) for each distinct combination of fields in the Pivot Table, or is something else happening? I guess I'm really asking about the order of operations for this Calculated Field

Answer (score 0):

Using `AVERAGEIFS`:

`AVERAGEIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,A2,$B$2:$B$9,B2)`

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can add up to 127 conditions, see: [AVERAGEIFS function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

> Criteria_range1, criteria_range2, …     are 1 to 127 ranges in which
>   to evaluate the associated criteria.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are getting at, but I do not see how this can be extended to a Pivottable. I actually have **seven** categorical fields like year and region, not just the two.

Comment: Also, could you try to make your response a little more educational? I am kind of a complete n00b when it comes to Excel.